# Triple integral through Gauss theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

We are asked to calculate as triple integral, through Gauss theorem, the surface integral of
$z^2dxdy+x^2dydz+y^2dzdx$.
We are given $D$ through the expression $0\leq x,y,z\leq 1$.
I found that ${\rm div}(F)=0$, where $F=(z^2,x^2,y^2)$.
Thus the triple integral through Gauss theorem is zero.

I would appreciate if you could guide me whether the specific way of thinking is correct.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please note your mistake is in the vector field. $F = (x^2, y^2, z^2)$. As the question seeks you to apply Gauss Theorem and calculate using triple integral, it should be $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 2 (x+y+z) \ dx \ dy \ dz$. You can also see that due to symmetry the integral of $2x, 2y$ and $2z$ are same, which is $1$ each.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the requested surface integral is not zero. Note that the surface integral of $z^2dxdy$ is $1$ on the top face and zero over the other $5$ faces of the cube $[0,1]^3$. By symmetry the surface integral of $z^2dxdy+x^2dydz+y^2dzdx$ is equal to $3$.

The same result can be obtained by applying Gauss' Divergence Theorem:
let $F$ be a given smooth vector field, then
$$\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]^3} {\rm div}(F)\,dV &= \int_S F \cdot n\,dS\\
&=\iint_{ [0,1]^2} F(x,y,0) (0,0,-1)\,dxdy+\iint_{ [0,1]^2} F(x,y,1) (0,0,1)\,dxdy\\
&+\iint_{ [0,1]^2} F(0,y,z) (-1,0,0)\,dydz+\iint_{ [0,1]^2} F(1,y,z) (1,0,0)\,dydz\\
&+\iint_{ [0,1]^2} F(x,0,z) (0,-1,0)\,dxdz+\iint_{ [0,1]^2} F(x,1,z) (0,1,0)\,dxdz.\end{align}$$
Now let $F=(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ and compare the two sides.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Really thank you very much! So I am going to calculate 6 surface integrals, thus 6 triple ones through Gauss theorem. Am I right?

Comment: OK, It is clear, thank you very much! Have a nice Easter!

Comment: @Vasilis I am glad that my answer was useful. BTW I presume you mean Orthodox Easter...

Comment: That's right, thank you!